How can I mark PTFE wires used at high temperatures under vacuum?
In our cryostat and high temperature (~200--250°C) setups, I use PTFE-insulated wires (compared to PVC it can take higher temperatures and outgasses less).  In sensible quantities the range of colours is less than the number of wires, and anyway a single reel is a lifetime's supply for our lab.  Our standard colour coding uses white for the devices under test and black for ground, but to avoid too many time-consuming pumping cycles we connect more devices simultaneously (up to 15) when running under vacuum; just counting the wires back to their feedthrough isn't likely to be reliable espeiclaly once they're tethered properly.  I want to mark the DUT end of the white wires with a sequential code.  They're 7/0.2 or 7/0.1, so thin but not stupidly so - we normally test pulsed operation at a few hundred mA.
In similar situations in the past I've tried:

Coloured heatshrink in a 2-band resistor-style colour code - it can't take the heat and is prone to outgassing.

Printable heatshrink - very nice, but the kit is too expensive.  Anyway it will soon end up brown all over at 200+°C.

Flag-like printed labels - not really enough room, they can't take the heat, and the glue is likely to outgas badly.

Marker pen stripes inspired by Roman numerals or abaci with a fat stripe for 5 and a thin stripe for 1 (e.g. ===|||==|==|=== for 7) - after labelling a set I tidied them up only for the dry marker (Sharpie) ink to end up on my hands - it doesn't stick to PTFE at all.

Cable ties in a similar pattern - no room.  These are individual wires going to the pins of a 16-pin TO-8 package in a tight space.


Other ideas inspired by those above:

PTFE heatshrink is available but only in clear.  It slides along the wires when handled unless shrunk over a joint or other fat bit.  Using it to protect the pen marks I tried  is my best idea, and we use it over the pin sockets which anchors it.  But running a long enough piece from the socket to cover the stripes means the wire is much less flexible right where we need it.

Paint markers - almost certain to flake off, not what you want in a vacuum system.


I feel like I'm missing something, maybe something obvious, that people working with similar wires in harsh environments might have come across before.

A couple of ideas below (or derivatives of them) were easy to try and will be tested soon:

On the left, Russell McMahon's contrasting wire made easier by it holding a twist well and covering with PTFE heatshrink, so I could try a wide and a narrow strip in one piece.  On the right Arsenal's kapton tape. This is 7/0.2.
Not so simple, but Spehro Pefhany's idea of laser marking works quite nicely with the 355nm output of our Ekspla NT3242B.  That's the best part of 100mJ per pulse in 5ns in about a 6mm beam, unfocussed. I'd need to focus it to get narrow stripes and hopefully a little more contrast.  The 2 wide stripes below were 10ish and 20ish pulses (based on the 10Hz repetition rate).  There were no fumes from the PTFE, unlike from our black plastic enclosure.


So many good answers, it's hard to know what to accept: cool physics and doable with kit I happen to have, or more practical, especially as I may use 2 ideas.  So far I've neither pumped nor baked anything so testing is ongoing

You could write your own answer detailing what you have done and tested and accept that in the end - would provide a good data point from all your testing. In the end, no one could say: do this, this works 100 %, so your testing is valuable.

Nice. What about masking the UV laser to get the narrow stripes? Maybe Kapton tape, perhaps notched with an Xacto knife?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I might try a cylindrical lens, which would increase the power density as well, so might make it darker.  I'm not sure I fancy scorching kapton tape in the lab, and would use metal if I needed a slit.  Plus a jig to hold the wire in the beam, let me rotate it for all-round marking, and  let me measure steps.

@Chris Maybe copper or aluminum tape?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany That's what I was thinking - we have aluminium tape, both regular shiny and black-coated.  We also have optical slits.  Heatsinks make good beam dumps and have straight edges that could be assembled together, but the black anodising doesn't last long with UV

Kapton tape survives temperatures like this.
The color choice is pretty limited as far as I've come across so far, but maybe you can use bar code style coding with different widths to encode the information on the cable.
I'm not sure how bad the outgassing is, but it's advertised for space usage, so hopefully there are some low outgassing ones around. From experience the glue was quite nice, so that after several cycles it would still come off quite nicely without leaving a nasty sticky mess.
I'm not sure how well it will hold on PTFE wires, I guess this might be an issue.

We've got a couple of widths of translucent orange and dark brown.  The orange isn't sticky enough (a shame as I could use pen underneath it if it was). The brown looks like it might be (to wrap round and stick to itself; it sticks only weakly to the PTFE but enough to keep it in place).  There's some on my test piece.

@ChrisH in high vacuum ($$<3\times10^{-9}$$ torr) we just wrote in sharpie on kapton (but only when critical, I'm sure sharpie ink isn't the ideal high vacuum material), but we also had the relative luxury of being able to let it outgas as we only pumped down rarely. You can also of course use some sort of code of number of pieces of tape stuck on wire/notches cut in the tape after sticking instead of the sharpie. We also had no issues with the translucent orange tape staying put when wrapped around a wire sticky side to sticky side (but we didn't have teflon insulation)

@llama that's a good data point, thanks. For vacuum insulation we only need 10^-5 or 6, but we might need to pump down several times in a day on the high temp kit. Our orange kapton didn't stick very well to the PTFE when I tried it yesterday, but maybe well enough for a flag-like label that mostly sticks to itself (and the dark brown didn't show Sharpie).

Laser marking comes to mind. It does not add any materials other than
whatever decomposes under the laser. (image from above link):


Direct printing on wires and cables with Ultra-violet (UV) lasers has
been extensively tested and accepted within the aerospace industry
both by OEMs and by the end users. It is covered by several documents
and standards issued by SAE International (http://www.sae.org/
AIR5558, AIR5468B, AS5649) and reflected in the production
specification of large and small frame aircrafts for commercial,
industrial, and military use. The OEM list includes Boeing, Airbus,
Lockheed Martin, Sikorsky, Gulfstream, Bombardier, Pilatus, and many
others. It is also used by governmental agencies such as DOD, NASA,
FAA, etc. End users employ UV laser marking machines during scheduled
maintenance and repair procedures.

The NIH reminds us:

When heated to above 750 °F, (PTFE) decomposes to yield highly toxic fumes of
fluorides.

So using a consumer UV laser might not be wise without some precautions, but
professional suppliers should have some ways of dealing with the fumes.

That sounds fun.  By sheer coincidence one of the setups I'm thinking of is right next to a broadly tunable ps laser, and in the next lab to a ns laser with 355nm available.  What really interesting is that it's not a thermal effect so the generation of fumes should be low if the power is sensible. Given the simplicity of the markings I need, we could have a play.

Might be possible to laser-mark transparent heatshrink tube, which often starts flat. This would save problems caused by "wrap around" due to the geometry of fine wire.

@MarkMorganLloyd the non-thermal process for PTFE relies on the whiteness (the TIO₂ used to make it white and opaque) but with normal heatshrinl it would be more likely

It works rather nicely - I've put a picture and some details in the question

Colored beads? You could slip on as disconnected, remove as each connection is made.

Coloured PTFE sleeving. Thin tube intended to be slipped over bare wires, often available in quite short lengths, 1 m or a few, and various diameters. Cut into very short tubes, 1 or 2 mm, so forming short and thin 'beads', and assemble onto the wires in a coded pattern, Roman numerals, binary, resistor colour codes, whatever.
I don't know how many grades of PTFE are available. I would not be surprised if 'PTFE sleeving', especially coloured varieties intended for high temperature protection of bare wires, outgassed to a degree unsuitable for high vacuum. But presumably you will test them.

There's more choice than I thought but keeping it at the right end of the wire could be interesting, Perhaps a 2-colour pattern held in place by looping the wire through and some clear PTFE heatshrink to hold it together.

you could tie a simple overhand knot in the wire to keep the bits of tube at the correct end.

True.  I'm normally not keen on knotting wires because it stresses them, but in this case it would be OK

This suggested method is somewhat slow and fiddly, but would probably get fast enough with experience.
Mark the wires with wraps of a few turns of coloured PTFE wire with ends stripped and wrapped together.  This could use as few as two colours if a binary code is acceptable, but multiple colours will rapidly improve the information per effort.
If you wanted to minimise the length of the stripped section you could runa horizontal length of marker wire along the marked wire and then wrap backwards towards the starting point.
Wire ends could be twisted with some risk of coming undone or "soldered" with a suitable material.

PTFE 7/0.2 holds a twist pretty well without stripping (BTW stripping short lengths is fiddly as the insulation doesn't grip the metal or the strippers/hand very well).  Secured with clear PTFE heatshrink it's possible to mark it with a single contrasting colour.

I'd suggest also considering bare copper wire, or MW 16-C (or 16-A if you can find it) magnet wire. That way, you can mark the wire without increasing the diameter so much--30 gauge bare copper is about 10 mils diameter, for instance. You'd need more turns for the same width of marking, though.

A few thoughts:

I would not normally commend this, but you could tie patterns of knots into the wires, like an aztec quipu, perhaps using a base-3 or base-4 code.

Make small marked metal tags for the wires.

Lightly crimp marked metal sleeves to the wires.

Lightly crimp length-encoded sets of metal sleeves to the wires.

Don't worry about the marking.  Use a continuity probe after connection the find the current mapping between pins and test devices.  In fact, checking the mapping is probably a sensible thing to do anyway.



I have used miniature washer (M1) made from brass to mark cables in hot conditions.

from amazon
If you use different materials like brass, copper, steel or anodized metal, you could colorcode each wire. Make sure that your material stays the same color, mine look not as shiny as the ones which stayed cool.Outgassing shouldn't be a problem with plain metals.
To make them stay in the same positions use a knot on both sides or pass the wire a few times around them.

+1 Or slide clear PTFE heatshrink over them (also protects them from potentially coming into contact with device pins and causing shorts)

Brass should be avoided in high vacuum because of its zinc content causing outgassing (vapour pressure of Zn is a few E-5 torr at 500 K) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materials_for_use_in_vacuum#Materials_to_avoid

There are a number of different types of textiles that are designed to handle extreme environments (think the protective suits worn by firemen). You can knot strands of thread around your wires to mark them. Threads take up practically no space, and they should stay put if you pull them tight enough.
For example, Kevlar thread can survive over 400C and does not melt.  PTFE coated fiberglass is another option. It has the same coating as your wires, so it should have the same thermal limits.  These types of specialist materials are far more expensive than normal thread, but you won't need very much of it.
Oddly enough, plain old wool thread may also be an option.  It doesn't melt and the autoignition point is above 550 C. It'll burn if directly exposed to a flame, but I doubt that's the case in your test chamber. It's also inexpensive and easy to source.  It comes in every color imaginable, but you'll have to test whether the dyes will outgas under those conditions. Undyed thread shouldn't have anything to outgas, you'll just have to use a knot coding system instead of color coding.

If you tried to put wool in my vacuum system I would make you spend the next month ensuring that you had removed every single fibre it had shed inside the chamber, lol. Surface area should be generally minimized in vacuum, natural fibres have a lot of surface area. Kevlar thread might be a reasonable idea though.

I've got some nonwoven nomex "paper" sheet from an earlier iteration of the high temp experiment. That was nitrogen purged rather than under vacuum and I sewed it with cotton thread (I looked at kevlar thread and decided I couldn't justify the cost). As @llama says, natural fibres aren't going near my vacuum system, and even synthetics should be monofilament to reduce surface area and shedding (a small restriction as kevlar fibre is often monofilament). Your first sentence suggests that the nomex sheet might work as labels.

@ChrisH You may also want to look into the materials that NASA uses for cable lacing. Those cords are designed to spend months/years in a vacuum without shedding or deteriorating. They've used a variety of materials, including heat-resistant things like Teflon and Nomex.  Some industries still do cable lacing, so it's likely still on the market somewhere.

Knots.
The Incas recorded information that way, called Quipu
You could simply use the number of knots as a unary / tally system, count the knots.
Or, with a simple overhand for '0' and a figure-8 for '1', you have a binary code.
Knots with more turns and interesting shapes are available to increase the size of the alphabet, but it could strain the readability of the symbols.
You have commented that knotting wires stresses them, but that's what stranded wire is for, it's much more flexible than the equivalent cross section of solid wire.

PTFE 7/0.1 is rather limiting in the knots that hold shape nicely; figure-8s tend to relax. But overhand and a double overhand stopper (or better a triple version of it) as commonly used in sewing threads would give a pair of symbols. Playing with ideas around single-rope braids at my desk got me some funny looks in work

@ChrisH Yes, I'm actually a knot geek, so I toned it waaay down. The double-fishermans is perhaps my favourite base knot. Counting the turns in a braid or knot is quite difficult, if it's in 7/0.1.

I've tied too many double and triple fisherman's in thin cord recently (custom phone lanyards) - knots are something I can do, with reference materials, but not a real skill. I was thinking more of wise and narrow knots as 5s and 1s in a tally, rather than counting turns

I'd just use labels, in other words a strip of flex PCB with a hole in it ;)

(pic source)
You can get custom flex PCB for a very low cost at JLCPCB and other outlets. It comes with silkscreen and copper, which you can use for your labeling needs, and of course with holes to thread your PTFE wire through. It should survive your temperatures nicely.

I wonder how vacuum-compatible it is, not having worked with flexible PCBs before but knowing that rigid increases pumping times due to outgassing.  With 2 holes it could stay in place quite nicely, but it would have to be in very small piece for this application (16-pin TO-8 has about a 2.5mm pitch and there's no space to put the labels anywhere other than close to the pins)

I don't have data about outgassing, but intuitively it should be similar to kapton tape... speaking of which, here are kapton PCB labels which are meant to survive reflow soldering, perhaps you can find blank ones in a suitable size: http://fr.mietiketten.com/high-temperature-label/smt-labels/kapton-polyimide-pcb-barcode-labels-15-x-6mm.html

Another feature of the holes in flex pcb is you can group wires in bundles too. But... why not use fixed sockets at the end of the wires?

we use trailing single pin sockets .  There's no room for a full size socket, and for thermal reason the can (just a base) has to be the physical mount

I found a label with "low outgassing", the KTT version in this document https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/TE%20Kapton%20Labels.pdf

It appears to be only rated for 150C, but I think it might be worth trying ETFE wire. I've bought it from ProWireUSA, they advertise it as Tefzel insulation and sell it by the foot in about 10 different colors.
Link: https://www.prowireusa.com/tefzel-wire.html

200°C really is the minimum in one kit. I'm hoping to avoid hitting the 250°C limit of a lot of what I've been using, because things get much harder after that.
